# TS2305: has no exported member when importing from a barrel file

Tags: typescript, react-native, webpack, import, export

I am using webpack and typescript in expo application
I have 2 TS files then export functions for example:

```
// folder/file1.ts
export function func1() { ... };

// folder/file2.ts
export function func2() { ... };
```

and I created a barrel index.ts:

```
// folder/index.ts
export * from "./file1";
export * from "./file2";
```

Now, I wanted to use it in another TS file, simply importing those func1() and func2():

```
// different-folder/some-other-file.ts
import { func1, func2 } from "../folder";
```

But here I get the error:

TS2305: Module has no exported member 'func1'

and same for func2.

Do you have an idea how to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You could export component like this:

```
// folder/index.ts
```

const file1 from "./file1";
const file2 from "./file2";

export {
file1, file2
}